# cmake find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python) fails but other boost packages work

Tags: boost, cmake, boost-python

I am using cmake (v3.17.3) to build a starter project that uses some boost (1.73) packages. The boost packages are managed with vcpkg (20.02.04-nohash). To date I have had success. Boost packages and statements like

`find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem system unit_test_framework REQUIRED)`

result in successful builds. However, when I add boost:python, i.e.

`find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem system unit_test_framework python REQUIRED)`

I receive the following error from cmake:

> [cmake] CMake Error at E:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164 (message):
> [cmake]   Could NOT find Boost (missing: python) (found version "1.73.0")

I can confirm that boost-python:x64-windows package is installed on my machine - in the same way that the other, working boost packages were installed (vcpkg install boost-pkg:x64-windows).

Other information that may be relevant. Windows 10, VSCode 1.46.0.

I'm pretty new to cmake and vcpkg but would really like to get this to work in VSCode so that I can port the project to a different OS.

Comment: Read [FindBoost documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/module/FindBoost.html): "Note that Boost Python components require a Python version suffix (Boost 1.67 and later), e.g. python36 or python27 for the versions built against Python 3.6 and 2.7, respectively."

Comment: Many thanks Felipe. This answers my question. I'm now able to move onto the next: How to get vcpkg to install boost-python for a specific python version (3.7) rather than the latest (3.8). There are many documents to read before getting a starter project to work ...